# Formula in Google Sheets should return a text string representing a date, but returns integer instead

Tags: google-sheets

I have a string like:

```
Season_Week_Campaign_Audience_Sender_20AUG2020_A
```

I want to extract the string "20AUG2020", so I entered the following formula:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT('Raw Data'!A2:A,"_"),,6)
```

However it's returning the number `44671`. I haven't been able to find any formula that will allow me to keep the string formatted as a string. There must be something very basic I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TEXT with UPPER to get around that

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(ISBLANK('Raw Data'!A2:A),,
   UPPER(
    TEXT(
     INDEX(SPLIT('Raw Data'!A2:A,"_"),,6),
     "DDMMMYYY"))))
```

or use a little REGEX to pull the string directly

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),,
   REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,".*_(\w+)_")))
```

The pattern might need a little refinement based on your data, but this assumes that all values have an underscore, the formatted date, and another underscore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the text function:

```
=TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT('Raw Data'!A2:A,"_"),,6),"DD-MMM-YYYY")
```

Or use:

```
=TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT('Raw Data'!A2:A,"_"),,6),"DDMMMYYYY")
```